# java selenium thread synchronization bruteforce

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization, thread-safety

This is for testing proposes (nothing bad)

I want to make a bruteforce program with Selenium 2 who breaks in a "0 to 10" password protected page

i have this (a tiny example not the actual code) ...

```
public class test implements Runnable {

    static WebDriver driver;

    test() {
        StageLoader();
        Thread t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

    //starts firefox and goes to the page
    private void StageLoader() {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://test.com/login.php");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            bruteForce(i);
        }
    }

    private void bruteForce(int i) {

        driver.findElement(
                By.name("password"))
                .sendKeys(Integer.toString(i));

        String output = driver.findElement(By.id("result")).getText();

        if (output.indexOf("sucess") != -1) {
            //stop
        } else {
            //continue
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FiberBrute();
    }
}
```

it works perfectly but it lacks synchronization, i want it to go from 0 to 10 one by one and only continue with the next if !success, i already tried a lot to make this works with concurrency but i failed :( can you help me a little please ?

thanks in advance :D

Comment: So the part you're trying to multithread is the bruteForce method?  So that it can try 1-3 in parallel, then 4-6 etc?

Comment: If you wait until the previous attempt either passes or fails, you're single threaded and don't need synchronization.  What is happening in parallel here?  Multiple users each going 1-10?

Comment: problem is that the for loop goes all at once, i need to do something in order to wait until the first try is finished, then wait for the second try, and so on ... for example, if 1 is not success try 2, if 2 is not sucess try 3, etc ... what i have now tries 0 to 10 all at once is a mess :P

Answer (score 0):

The example code here as written should go 1 by 1, but it won't stop on success.

```
@Override
public void run() {
    // Go until we run out of numbers or bruteForce comes back with 'true'
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10 && !bruteForce(i); i++);                    
}

//Returns true if it found the password
private boolean bruteForce(int i) {

    driver.findElement(
            By.name("password"))
            .sendKeys(Integer.toString(i));

    String output = driver.findElement(By.id("result")).getText();

    if (output.indexOf("sucess") != -1) {
        //stop
        return true;
    } else {
        //continue
        return false;
    }

}
```

In order for all 10 attempts to happen at once, bruteForce would need to be spawning threads, which it isn't doing here.